# Scope and participants in the Oracle Contributor Agreement

Tags: contract-law, intellectual-property, software, patents

Reading the [Oracle Contributor Agreement](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/oca-486395.html) ([direct PDF link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/oca-405177.pdf)), there are some points which seem off, at least for me as someone with zero legal knowledge.

The first paragraph defines:

> The term “us” shall mean Oracle International
>   Corporation. The term “you” shall mean the person or entity identified below.

yet in point 2 it says:

> you agree that each of us can do all things in relation to your contribution as if each of us were the sole owners ...

Does that mean only Oracle has this right, as "us" was defined to refer solely to them? Or could "us" in this case be understood as Oracle **and** the signee?

Answer (score 1):

The operative phrase here is "each of us", which does not make sense with the agreement's definition of "us" (which, for starters, is not plural). Absent a definition that makes sense, "each of us" can be reasonably interpreted as the common English phrase (which in this case would refer to "each of the parties to this agreement").

In short, Oracle appears to have meant for you to have that right as well.

(Even if they didn't, as the drafters of the agreement, they are responsible for clearly stating terms. When they fail to do so, the ambiguity will generally be interpreted in your favor. Google: "contra proferentem".)